# How to make tagged union (aka sum type) in ROS message?

Tags: ros2

I would like the equivalent of protobuf's `Oneof` in my ROS messages. Is there a pattern for how to replicate this functionality in a ROS message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rosidl doesn't have a native way to support that. The pattern most commonly used is to do variable length arrays of each data type. It doesn't enforce the one part but you can gather a few different types.

```
TypeA[] field_one
TypeB[] field_two
TypeC[] firld_three
```

Then you code which would have done a switch based on which type is in the `OneOf` now will do `if field_one ... else if field_two ... else ...`

You should define behavior for multiple elements and if none are populated.

This works without needing to define a whole new construct, and let's us keep direct member based access for all the fields.

Comment: Won't this technically make a much larger message size, as each variable-length array will need to transmit a size of 0? This approach makes smaller messages than the style where you have a field for each type (assuming most types are larger than the size type), but it is still much larger than a tagged union type should be (discriminator + largest type). This also does not offer good ergonomics because I don't understand how one might write a generic function that would convert these sorts of messages into a tagged union. One could write a conversion function for each message.

Comment: The size tradeoff I think will depend on the data types. It's sizes for each unused array, and the actively selected data type, versus the selector and the largest data type.  You could potentially write a generic converter using some of the introspection APIs, but what I'm pointing out is a functional substitute but not a direct replacement. For any specific message you could make a custom type adapter in C++. But my understanding is that union data types aren't universally available with the exact same semantics in all languages so it will be hard to make something fully generic.

Comment: It is a fair observation that C++ does not make sum types first class anyway, as there is no language support, and so you are left with language types like variants or using c unions when you need to interact with one. Your point is well taken that might extend the code generation for messages to give more ergonomic interfaces. I appreciate this is a nicer alternative than any of the others I have seen. Something similar seems to be done also for optional fields relying on the array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible given the need for a deterministic byte-layout of messages. The only variable-size concept are arrays. With those first the length of the array is written into the byte buffer, followed by all values. See, e.g., [here](https://github.com/RethinkRobotics-opensource/rosnodejs/blob/eacfffc8231e584f92476c5be3a695ac0633bcfb/src/utils/messageGeneration/messages.js#L554).

Comment: Would a tagged union (the first byte is the tag, next bytes are a size determined by that tag as it tells you the type of the next set of bytes) not be deterministic?

Comment: Here are docs on the Union type from the idl docs for the dds vendors. Something like this is what I'd like:
- fastdds: https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastddsgen/dataTypes/dataTypes.html#unions
- cyclone: https://cyclonedds.io/content/guides/supported-idl.html#:~:text=A%20union%20in%20IDL%20is,can%20define%20a%20default%20member.